# Giving Multiple Ids for stream in facebook FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

```
select post_id, message from stream where source_id IN (..., ..., ...) LIMIT 500
```

I'm using this fql query but it is returning just few posts. While the below query is returning more than 200 posts.

```
select post_id, message from stream where source_id = ... LIMIT 500
```

but giving same id with other id is returning 4 to 5 posts.

I know fql support is not available in v2.0 but still I want to do this using fql.

Comment: FQL is still usable in v2.0 until 30th of April, 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems strange... Have you tried doing this via pure Graph API? What kind of objects are you using as `source_id`s?

```
GET /?ids={object_id_1},{object_id_2},{object_id_3}&fields=feed.fields(id,message).limit(100)
```

Comment: as a source id i'm using user id to fetch their posts